# nightwatch failed to select element by its id

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I have below HTML dom on my page. And I use ngithwatch to write test cases.

```
<td class="GPNWDJGHV" id="gwt-debug-MenuItem/mongo-true">Mongo Extension</td>
```

If I use below code to select the dom's id, it will not find the element:

```
.waitForElementVisible('#gwt-debug-MenuItem/mongo-true', 10000)
```

but if I use classname it will works as below.

```
.waitForElementVisible('GPNWDJGHV', 10000)
```

the only different is that the id contains a character '/'. Is this the problem nightwatch not picking it up? What is the way to use id name with special character?

**EDIT1**

I have tried to add '\' in the id like below:

```
.waitForElementVisible('#gwt-debug-MenuItem\/mongo-true', 10000)
```

it still doesn't work. But this selector works in css. Not sure how different in nightwatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with Selenium or Nightwatch, but only with HTML IDs. `/` is not a valid character for ID.

**XPath** uses `/` to select child nodes from a parent node:
http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_xpath.asp

w3schools has a very simple example to test that: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_id

**Edit:** Probably you can escape the slash in the CSS selector with `\/`. (Note: I only tested it on the w3schools demo (using `id="first/name"`).)

HTML:

```
<td class="GPNWDJGHV" id="gwt-debug-MenuItem/mongo-true">Mongo Extension</td>
```

JS:

```
.waitForElementVisible('#gwt-debug-MenuItem\/mongo-true', 10000);
```

Comment: I find no problem with id containing / (forward slash). I tested it with Java binding.

Comment: I tested the w3schools demo again: Obviously you can use an escaped forward slash. Just updated the answer. How does your Java binding example handle the forward slash?

Comment: I just tried to use \ on the id. It works for css selector but doesn't work with nightwath

Comment: From a design point of view, I'd try to avoid forward slashes in HTML IDs. If you want to did deeper nevertheless, probably you want to take a look at how nightwatch handles these chars internally.